# How do you tell who is who after you die?

Tags: town-of-salem

I've been told that after you die, you can tell who has what role, but I have yet to be able to see that. Is this actually possible and if so, then how can I see this information?

Answer (score 4):

You can't until the game ends (because of cheating issues). When it does finish in the screen after the "Mafia Wins" appears (or whoever wins), you see a screen that tells you the Salem Username, in game name and role of each person.

See the screengrab below (it's taken from someone's Youtube channel as I can't be bothered to actually play a game to ge the screengrab!)

[image: Post game screenshot]